# package .proto files into a separate jar and publish it to a remote repository

Tags: scala, sbt

I am very new to scala and hardly any experience with build.sbt. I have a scala project with .proto files inside src/main/proto directory. I need to package these proto files into a separate jar using build.sbt and publish it to a remote repository. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [How to share .proto files using a shared scala library using sbt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71750658/how-to-share-proto-protobuf-files-using-a-shared-scala-library-using-sbt/71760018#71760018)